# angular directive - interpolation issues when calling a function in an attribute in the template function that is defined in the link method

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Ok, learning angular directives at the moment and became stuck with one problem.

I have a directive where in the linking function there is a function created that is linked to the scope which is called on the template function as an attribute in a html element. It is also called in-between the html tags as well. Neither of the tags update. I suspect it is not compiled yet or something. However, I can not understand the documentation as it seems to talk about too many things at once and doesn't make much sense. Or they have omitted some key information.

Either way below is a snapshot of my code.

{{labelText()}} does not update/interpolate. Any help with a solution would be great!

```
var app = angular.module('mmApp', []);
app.directive('mmField', function(){

    return {
        'restrict': 'E',
        'priority': 5,
        'replace': true,
        'scope': {
            'path': '@',
            'label': '@',
            'type': '@',
            'editable': '@'
        },
        'template': '<div class="mm-field">' +
            '<label for="{{inputId()}}" ng-show="labelText()">{{labelText()}}</label> ' +
            '</div>',

        'link': function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var query = null;
//this is where the labelText() function is defined
            scope.labelText = function () {
                var labelAttrValue = (scope.label || attrs['withLabel'] || '');
                // cater for custom labels specified via the label or with-label attribute
                if (labelAttrValue && labelAttrValue.toLowerCase() !== 'true' && labelAttrValue.toLowerCase() !== 'false') {
                    return (labelAttrValue || '') + ':';
                } else if (labelAttrValue.toLowerCase() !== 'false' && scope.field) {
                    return (scope.field['name'] || 'FIELD_NAME_NOT_DEFINED') + ':';
                } else if (labelAttrValue.toLowerCase() == 'false') {
                    return '';
                } else {
                    return 'Loading...';
                }
            };
        }
}
])
```

My test function is below. Using mocha and chai testing suite.

```
describe('LabelText', function () {
            it('should compile and run the directive and interpolate labelText()', function () {
                var element = $($compile('<div id="#test">' +
                    '<mm-field with-label="MONKEY" editable="false" path="`enter something.name"></mm-field>' +
                    '</div>')($scope));
                $scope.$digest();
                expect(element.find('label').attr('ng-show')).to.not.equal(labelText()); //test fails and equals labelText()
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's merely syntax problem somewhere.

I copied your code and ran it in my local. I got it to work but only after fixing some mismatched curly brackets and removed all of the dependency injections you put in there, as none of them is used in the link function.

```
directive('mmField', function () {
  return {
    'restrict': 'E',
    'priority': 5,
    'replace': true,
    'scope': {
      'path': '@',
      'label': '@'
    },
    'template': '<div class="mm-field">' +
    '<label for="{{inputId()}}" ng-class="labelClass()" ng-show="labelText()">{{labelText()}}</label> ' +
    '<span class="field-value" ng-class="spanClass()" ng-click="handleSpanClick($event)" ng-show="!error">{{displayValue}}  <span class="units" ng-show="getUnits()">{{getUnits()}}</span></span> ' +
    '</div>',
    'link': function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var query = null;

      scope.labelText = function () {
        var labelAttrValue = (scope.label || attrs['withLabel'] || '');

        if (scope.error) return scope.error;

        // cater for custom labels specified via the label or with-label attribute
        if (labelAttrValue && labelAttrValue.toLowerCase() !== 'true' && labelAttrValue.toLowerCase() !== 'false') {
          return (labelAttrValue || '') + ':';
        } else if (labelAttrValue.toLowerCase() !== 'false' && scope.field) {
          return (scope.field['name'] || 'FIELD_NAME_NOT_DEFINED') + ':';
        } else if (labelAttrValue.toLowerCase() == 'false') {
          return '';
        } else {
          return 'Loading...';
        }
      };
      scope.inputId = function () {
        return scope.path.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi, '_');
      };
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for looking.


However, just focus on the scope.labelText function where it is called in the compiled function in the mocha test function.

It works fine, not syntax error although I may have copied and pasted it incorrectly when trying to remove parts of the code not needed.

Basically the result I am getting is that the function is not being evaluated.

the result of the attribute is ng-show="labelText()" not ng-show="some evaluated value".

Also it is not evaluated in the whitespace as well where the {{}} is.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I wish I could help but you code is making it much more difficult than it should be. Codes provided in questions should be complete and free of syntax errors, so that people like I can try to run and debug the code in our local. As for your code, aside from the syntax error mentioned earlier, you testing code seems to have missing pieces. For eg, you use `$compile` service without injecting ahead of time. And `expect(element.find('label').attr('ng-show')).to.equal();`, what are you expecting the ngShow attribute found in the `<label>` tag to equal to?

Comment: Please fill in the holes in your code and make sure it's syntax-error free before posting and asking for help on SO. Otherwise, the chances are you won't get the answer/help you need. Even worse, other users might flag your question as low-quality and the question could very likely be taken off by moderators. Click on the "update" link right below your post and make the appropriate changes and preview the result before submitting. Thank you on behalf of the community.